# Finding a set of characters

Tags: c, recursion, computer-science

So you are to read in integers c and m. C is the number of cases, m is the number of lines per case. After m, there are m lines containing any number of letters, no doubles (a-z). After those lines there is an int r, which is the solution number we want if we did recursion for every possible result having one letter from each line, forming a string.

There is a way to skip recursion, and go straight to the rank (int r) that we want. I am having a problem with my pointers by trying to send my struct into functions. Any help would be great. Here is a sample of my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 26
//Struct to hold all information inside
struct passwordT{
char letters[MAX];
int charCount;
int possibleSkips;
int solutionArray;
};

//Functions. numOfSkips gets number of solutions to skip for each line, and getSol gets the array for the  
lines of chars.
passwordT* numOfSkips(passwordT *T, int *total, int m);
int getSol(int ps, int v, int m, int r);



int main(){
int i, j, k;
int c, m, r;
char p;
int total = 0;

//Read in Number of cases
scanf("%d", &c);

//Declaring a pointer to struct passwordT, then making mallocing for the size of the number of cases
passwordT* ptrToPass;
ptrToPass = malloc(c*sizeof(passwordT));

//Cycle through cases
for (i=0; i<c;i++){

    //Read in number of lines
    scanf("%d", &m);

    //Reading in the string on each line
    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
        scanf("%s", &ptrToPass[j].letters);
    }

    //Get number of characters for each string
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){
        ptrToPass[j].charCount = 0;
        k=0;
        p = ptrToPass[j].letters[0];
        while(p!='\0'){
            ptrToPass[j].charCount ++;
            k++;
            p = ptrToPass[j].letters[k];
        }
    }

    //Scan in solution number wanted
    scanf("%d", &r);

    //Get number of solutions to skip
    ptrToPass = numOfSkips(ptrToPass, &total, m);

    //Get solution set
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        ptrToPass[j].solutionArray = getSol(ptrToPass[j].possibleSkips, 1, m, r);

    //Print results
    for(j=0;j<m;j++)
        printf("%c", ptrToPass[j].letters[ptrToPass[j].solutionArray]);
}

return 0;
}

//This struct is for an algorithm used to skip to int r without recursion
passwordT* numOfSkips(passwordT *T, int *total, int m){

passwordT *skippers;
int i = 0;

//If i = 0, possible solution skips is 1. Else, possible solution skips for skippers[i] is total. Then total = 
total times current lines char count
for(i=0;i<m;i++){

    if(i==0){
        skippers[i].possibleSkips = 1;
        total = skippers[i].charCount;
    }

    else{
        skippers[i].possibleSkips = total;
        total = total * skippers[i].charCount;
    }
}
}


// Function used to get the array of the solution (int r) would be if we used recursion
int getSol(int ps, int v, int m,int r){
int sa = 0;
int i;
for(i=0; i<m; i++){
    while(v <= r - ps){
        sa ++;
        v += sa;
    }
}

return sa;

}
```

These are my errors:

```
12: syntax error before '*' token (Declaration of first function numOfSkips in header
13: warning, data definition has no type or storage class

IN MAIN

28: passwordT undeclared, first use in this function ( so when i have passwordT* ptrToPass;)
28: ptrtoPass undeclared

IN numOfSkips

73: syntax error before '*'--> error with passwordT* numOfskips(passwordT *T, int *total, int m){
79: m undeclared (first use in this function) --> First time I use m in function numOfSkips
83: total undeclared (same situation as line 79)
```

Comment: *"I am having a problem with my pointers by trying to send my struct into functions."*  That is not much of a problem description.  Are you getting a compile time error?  A run-time crash?  Unexpected output (for what input?)?  **"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the *specific problem*."**

Comment: It is not even compiling. I well comment my errors

Comment: line 54: ppassing arg 1 of 'numOfSkips' from incompatible pointer type

line 54: assignment from incompatible pointer type

in functions NumOfSkips

line 75: invalid use of undefined type 'struct passwordT'

75: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

76: invalid use of undefined type 'struct passwordT'

76: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

80: invalid use of undefined type 'struct passwordT'

80: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

81: invalid use of undefined type 'struct passwordT'

81: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Comment: I'd do it but counting to 54 myself? Nah... Seriously, put comments in the code where problem occurs. Also it's a question to debug your code line by line. Seems you expected your code to be perfect the way you wrote it, but it didn't. So just put all the code with all the warning without even trying to debug it yourself. I'm strongly against that kind of behaviour.

Comment: The problems just lie with my structs and functions. All my errors are with passing my struct into my functions

Answer (score 1):

You mix-and-match your use of `passwordT`.

Sometimes, you refer to it as `struct passwordT`, and sometimes you refer to it as a typedef.

I recommend **pick-one-and-stick-with-it**.

Your newest error message indicates that you don't have a C-99 compiler.
*(gee it really would've helped if you mentioned which compiler you were using when I first raised the issue...)*

Instead, try this (older-style) declaration:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char letters[MAX];
    int charCount;
    int possibleSkips;
    int solutionArray;
} passwordT;

passwordT* numOfSkips(passwordT *T, int *total, int m);
```

---

In this section of code, you treat `total` in different ways:

```
passwordT* numOfSkips(passwordT *T, int *total, int m){
[...]
total = skippers[i].charCount;
}
```

`total` is declared as a `pointer-to-int`, but you are treating it like it is an `int`.

Do you understand the difference between pointers and the types they point to?
What type do you mean for `total` to be?

I recommend prefixing variable names (especially pointers) to help you keep track of their types.
*(Now the name helps you remember its a pointer)*

```
passwordT* numOfSkips(passwordT *T, int *ptr_total, int m){
[...]
*ptr_total = skippers[i].charCount;
}
```

Comment: I just want the contents of the struct to be accesed in the function and keep the values once I am done with that function

Comment: And that m was supposed to be a c. I fixed it